# Angular Route not working, going different url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm newbie in AngularJS. My Angular-Route is not working. Here are all the files.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute']);
var myCtrl = function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Learning Angular';
  $scope.subTitle = 'Practice 8 (angular route)';

  $scope.dhaka = 'Hello Dhaka';
  $scope.chittagong = 'Hello Chittagong';
  $scope.rajshahi = 'Hello Rajshahi';
  $scope.khulna = 'Hello Khulna';
  $scope.rangpur = 'Hello Rangpur';
  $scope.mymensingh = 'Hello Mymensingh';
  $scope.sylhet = 'Hello Sylhet';
  $scope.barishal = 'Hello Barishal';
};

myApp.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/dhaka', {
      templateUrl: 'pg/dhaka.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl'
    })
    .when('/chittagong', {
      templateUrl: 'pg/chittagong.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl'
    })
    .when('/rajshahi', {
      templateUrl: 'pg/rajshahi.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl'
    })
    .when('/rangpur', {
      templateUrl: 'pg/rangpur.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl'
    })
    .when('/mymensingh', {
      templateUrl: 'pg/mymensingh.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl'
    })
    .when('/sylhet', {
      templateUrl: 'pg/sylhet.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl'
    })
    .when('/khulna', {
      templateUrl: 'pg/khulna.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl'
    })
    .when('/barishal', {
      templateUrl: 'pg/barishal.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl'
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myModule">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Practice</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="https://angularjs.org/favicon.ico">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- FontAwesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1 class="text-center">{{title}}</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center">{{subTitle}}</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#/dhaka">dhaka</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/chittagong">chittagong</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/rangpur">rangpur</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/rajshahi">khulna</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/khulna">khulna</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/sylhet">sylhet</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/barishal">barishal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/mymensingh">mymensingh</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <div class="" ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the following url, [the view is:](https://prnt.sc/k82fbz)

```
http://localhost/angularjs-practice/practice8/
```

Please follow the url when I hove on a link, the link is shown:

```
http://localhost/angularjs-practice/practice8/#/mymensingh
```

[here is the picture](http://prntscr.com/k82i64)

but, after clicking on the link request goes to different link:

```
http://localhost/angularjs-practice/practice8/#!#%2Fmymensingh
```

[here is the picture](http://prntscr.com/k82j9e)

**NO ERROR IN THE CONSOLE, 
but, 
still Rout is not working!**

here is the [github repo](https://github.com/an-amin/angularjs-practice/tree/master/practice8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put a '!' after '#' on the href.

```
<a href="#!/dhaka">dhaka</a>
...
...
<a href="#!/mymensingh">mymensingh</a>
```

now it's working

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#!dhaka">dhaka</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!chittagong">chittagong</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!rangpur">rangpur</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!rajshahi">khulna</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!khulna">khulna</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!sylhet">sylhet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!barishal">barishal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!mymensingh">mymensingh</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

the problem is the way you're mentioning your routes in the href tag , have a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: yes, I already have found the problem and solved this, works with `<a href="#!/dhaka">dhaka</a>` also